# How to set VS2010 environment

Tags: visual-studio-2010

After you install VS2010 and start it for the first time, your asked how you want your VS environment set, such as: C#, Web Developer, VB, etc...

How do you change this settings later?

Comment: Out of my experience, I didn't find a way to reset these settings. I did a reinstall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reset your settings

On the **Tools** menu, click **Import and Export Settings**.

On the **Welcome to the Import and Export Settings Wizard** page, click **Reset all settings** and then click **Next**.

You can then choose to save your old settings or not, then click **Next**.

In **Which collection of settings do you want to reset to**, select a settings collection from the list. This is where you choose for example C#.

Press **Finish** and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Tools menu >> Import and Export Settings >> Reset all settings. Follow the instructions of the wizard and choose the desired language as default development environment.